# I cannot open ipython qtconsole, it shows "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Yesterday everything works fine but I cannot open ipython qtconsole today. I did nothing during the night.
When I type

```
ipython qtconsole
```

in powershell, it shows:

```
PS C:\Users\Lucy> ipython qtconsole Error in sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\qtconsoleapp.py", line 41, in gui_excepthook
    old_excepthook(exctype, value, tb) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-112>", line 2, in initialize   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 386, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\qtconsoleapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    from qtconsole.qt import QtCore, QtGui   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\qt.py", line 23, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\qt_loaders.py", line 285, in load_qt
    result = loaders[api]()   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\qt_loaders.py", line 192, in import_pyqt4
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
```

And when I try to import pylab it shows nearly the same thing.

```
In [1]: import pylab
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-0c66bb86b884> in <module>()
----> 1 import pylab

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pylab.py in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.pylab import *
      2 import matplotlib.pylab
      3 __doc__ = matplotlib.pylab.__doc__

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py in <module>()
    272 from numpy.linalg import *
    273
--> 274 from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    275
    276 # provide the recommended module abbrevs in the pylab namespace

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
    107
    108 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
--> 109 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
    110
    111

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.pyc in pylab_setup()
     30     # imports. 0 means only perform absolute imports.
     31     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name,
---> 32                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
     33
     34     # Things we pull in from all backends

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py in <module>()
     15 from matplotlib.figure import Figure
     16
---> 17 from .backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
     18 from .backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAggBase
     19

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py in <module>()
     16
     17 from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
---> 18 from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
     19 from .backend_qt5 import QtGui
     20 from .backend_qt5 import FigureManagerQT

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py in <module>()
     29     figureoptions = None
     30
---> 31 from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
     32 from matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formsubplottool import UiSubplotTool
     33

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py in <module>()
     89     if QT_API in [QT_API_PYQT, QT_API_PYQTv2]:  # PyQt4 API
     90
---> 91         from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
     92
     93         try:

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
```

I really donnot know what to do with it. Please help me:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest Anaconda update you should run some complex command line string to launch qtconsole. Just look at the "Jupyther QTConsole" icon properties in the start menu:

```
C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3 "C:/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe" "C:/Anaconda3/Scripts/ipython-script.py" qtconsole
```

Comment: Yearh, it worked. Thanks very much! Maybe something wrong, I have never seen my jupyther icon, so I just typed this command line in the power shell. Hope they will fix this in the next update.